# Base class undefined error in C++

Tags: c++, header

---UPDATED ---

I have problems when including headers and cpp files in my project, so here are the files:
Person.h

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

class Person {
private:
string firstName;
string lastName;
long NID;

public:
Person();
void toString();

string get_firstName() {
    return firstName;
}

string get_lastName() {
    return lastName;
}

long get_NID() {
    return NID;
}
};

#endif
```

Teacher which extends Person
Teacher.h

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>

#ifndef TEACHER_H
#define TEACHER_H

class Teacher : public Person {
private:
int avg_horarium;

public:
Teacher();
void toString();

int get_avg_horarium() {
    return avg_horarium;
}
};

#endif
```

Then here is Teacher.cpp:

```
#include "Teacher.h"
using namespace std;

Teacher::Teacher() : Person() {
cout << "Enter average monthly horarium: ";
cin >> avg_horarium;
}

void Teacher::toString() {
Person::toString();
cout << "Average monthly horarium: " << avg_horarium;
}
```

The other class which extends Person is Student and since it's similar to teacher i won't poste it here. My question is what am i doing wrong to get all these errors on the screenshot:
http://s14.postimage.org/45k08ckb3/errors.jpg

Comment: You need some form of include guard. Also, definitely don't put `using namespace std;` in your header.

Comment: it's very much possible that you're up against the nemesis of every visual studio newbie: **precompiled headers**. remove the includes of "stdafx.h", and in the project properties dialog, under [Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled Headers], set "Precompiled Header" to "Not using precompiled headers". Then I suspect you'll get a whole slew of *other*, more real, errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your incorrect treatment of `stdafx.h` file. In MSVC compilers, when precompiled headers are enabled, everything before `#include "stdafx.h"` line is *ignored*.

Firstly, stop including `stdafx.h` into header (`.h`) files. `stdafx.h` is supposed to be included into implementation (`.cpp`) files. In your case, `#include "stdafx.h"` should be placed into `Person.cpp` and `Teacher.cpp`, not into `Person.h` and `Teacher.h`.

Secondly, either disable precompiled headers in your project, or make sure that `#include "stdafx.h"` is always *the very first* meaningful line in each of your implementation files. All other `#include` directives should go *after* `#include "stdafx.h"`, not before.

Comment: Okay so I disabled precompiled headers, but now it gives out meaningless errors like those: http://s18.postimage.org/5b1htuoo7/aaaaaa.png 
"stdafx.h" is now only included in main.cpp.

Comment: @Rosen Dimov: Well, now you have to fix these. What is `string` supposed to mean? In standard library the it is not `string`. It is `std::string`.

Comment: Okay, so I tried adding a 3rd class DatabaseManager which doesn't extend any of the other classes and when I try including Teacher.h inside DatabaseManager.cpp the following error occur: 
http://s9.postimage.org/e2a2wt8jh/teacher.jpg

My DatabaseManager.h file is here: 
http://s10.postimage.org/5d41zidnb/h_file.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In your header files put;

```
 #ifndef CLASSNAME_H
 #define CLASSNAME_H
```

At the top of the file, after `include` statements, before the class declaration. Put

```
#endif
```

At the bottom of the file after all the code. This ensures that the class is only defined once. Having multiple includes for the same header file often causes linking issues.

Comment: okay i added this stuff but now it gives out this error: http://s8.postimage.org/hmhz5hcfn/sadsads.jpg

Comment: @RosenDimov It's cause I left out the file name part. I'll add an edit.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but what value exactly should i assign to FILENAME. I tried Teacher.h or "Teacher.h" but it still produces errors.

Comment: @RosenDimov Your question wasn't dumb, my answer was sloppy. Try `TEACHER_H` or `PERSON_H` respectively.

Comment: @RosenDimov, Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but the name you use requires no relation to anything else, it just has to not be used anywhere else. `FILENAME_H` is a fairly common convention.

Comment: okay I updated my first post with code as it is now with all the corrections but still giving those meaningless errors: http://s18.postimage.org/5b1htuoo7/aaaaaa.png

Comment: @RosenDimov AndreyT's answer looks pretty good to me... Wouldn't know because when I was doing this type of crap in c++ that library was never included by default.

Comment: yeah after 100 or so attempts it compiled, his answer was absolutely accuarate, but thanks to you too guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just put into the header a guard

i.e

```
#ifndef _THIS_FILENAME
#define _THIS_FILENAME

wibble etc


#endif
```

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention use forward declarations - saves on the expense of recompilation.

Comment: [Bad name choice.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)